# Security and Privacy measures

Tags: security, privacy

Whats the most Bomb Proof Security  to protect h\d and data on it of all the programmes\options available.

Thank you all for what appears to be a debate.
I am actually looking for a way to protect my data on my fixed H\D as far as a hardware option is concerned nothing is much better than a micro sd really.. You can simply eat it :-).
However seriously I would be interested in a simple economic means to hide or make inaccessible certain directories and was wondering which was the best means to do this or at least make life difficult for who was trying to see the data.
Thanks

Comment: Is is possible for you to specify your question? Currently it is quite vague and very general. For example, what kind of attacks do you want to protect against? What kind of hardware is it stored on?

Comment: Physical security, plus using the machine as a standalone box without ever connecting to any network. This is impractical, so be prepared to compromise with whatever answer you go with. This is one of those questions where you can ask ten people and get ten different answers.

Answer (score 2):

Encryption. The desktop CD will offer to encrypt your home directory when you install. For a hard drive you can use LUKS or Truecrypt.

There is a graphical interface, cryptkeeper, in the repositories as well.

http://tom.noflag.org.uk/cryptkeeper.html

[image]

There is a small bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cryptkeeper/+bug/575918

There is a patch on that bug report and the work around is to whitelist cryptkeeper in dconf-editor , relevant key is `desktop/unity/panel/systray-whitelist`

See http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=10904044&postcount=6

Comment: Beware that there are ways to get past encryption, see http://xkcd.com/538/

Comment: Indeed, that is a classic, but, despite the shortcomings, still the best option.

Comment: I chose encryption on installation of 11.10 for instance but it must be very background as I cant say I have noticed it. Is it only encrypted if you try to examine the hard disc externally to your desktop?

Comment: @Antony depends on the encryption, but the desktop cd encrypts your home directory and it is automatically decrypted when you log in. Boot a live CD and try to examine your data.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen I will take a look from windows that should show it. How secure is this encryption? Can it be retro effected to other computers I have a laptop running 10,04 I dont remember being offered the option.

Answer (score 0):

The best "bomb-proof" security solution for hard-disks is NOT to use a software encryption solution.

For security solutions, you need to use a hardware solution.  For example (but not exclusively), companies such *stonewood* produce a hardware disk encryption mechanism that can only be unlocked via a separate hardware *token*.

As already stated, there are linux/open-source based solutions such as TrueCrypt and LUKS & dm-crypt.

Personally, GPG is a good solution for files & folders and is a portable solution.

Comment: Looks like Stonewood is now ViaSat, a UK company (Remember that in the UK you can be jailed for years for not turning over your encryption keys). I don't think I'd be willing to trust a proprietary device like that, either. Cool gadgets, but I could never fully trust it's absolute integrity.

Comment: ... I work with these devices day-in-day-out ... and no you will not be jailed for these encryption devices - very strange comment to make.  They are mandatory in certain sectors (i'm not a liberty to say what).  They have absolute integrity - I know the developers personally :) ... and no - I'm not a salesman, just a customer.

Comment: You might want to read the comment again, it's a valid point. I'm sure the devs are cool, but they are not immune from political and judicial pressures when making the drives. I'd buy one to protect my stuff from a competitor, sure, but 'Bomb Proof Security' it's not. I'm not disparaging the product, just making an observation and pointing out where their loyalties must be.

Comment: I Think Tom Brossman intended that if a court ordered you to hand over the data or the keys and you didnt this would be contempt. Maybe the best solution is to make things as invisible as possible. After all if you dont know its there you want try to crack it right? Maybe there is a fairly good encryption system that renders things invisible?